# can the amount of cash reserve ratio reserve bank of india gives back to banks or not

Tags: macroeconomics, banking, money

one instrument we have learnt like Cash reserve ratio .
supoose crr is 4% and one person deposit 100 rupee in bank.
now the crr is 4 it means out of 100 rupees 4 will go to rbi .my question is . can this rupee 4 rbi gives back to banks or not